# How perform streaming of .m4a song file with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play this song from itunes store while I'm downloading it

Why the code below doesn't play?

```
NSLog(@"start");

NSURL *songUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a1804.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/064/Music/v4/9b/b3/c7/9bb3c7dc-a06f-f18c-3e41-2ce1e36f73b4/mzaf_7432104896053262141.aac.m4a"];


NSError* errorVar = nil;
AVAudioPlayer* song = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songUrl error:&errorVar];
[song prepareToPlay];
[song play];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer.

Apple documentation suggests `AVAudioPlayer` is used for playback of audio data from a file or memory. `AVPlayer` works equally well with local and remote media files.

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:<#Live stream URL#>];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];
```

Refer [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
// soundUrl can be a remote url, don't need to be a file url
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
```